# Webpack: exclude certain svg files from being packed into app.js

Tags: webpack

I have a Vue.js application which is built with Webpack. I added a library with hundreds of SVG Flags. The scss file is quite small - and the flags are separate SVG files in a folder. When I build, Webpack puts all SVG files base64 encoded into app.js. In this special case this is counter productive, because it unnecessarily blows up the size of my app. I would rather like to load the flags from the SVG folder on demand, to keep my app small.

In App.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon.scss';
</style>
```

My Webpack Config has been created with vue-cli. It is from here:
https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/blob/v1/Vue_Starter/build/webpack.base.conf.js

The build contains the Flag-SVG files in the img path - so this is fine. 
But the Flag-SVGs are loaded as data from webpack, not directly from the img directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add some exceptions for the flags directory:

**original lines in configuration:**

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    },
  }
```

**modified lines in configuration:**

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    },
    exclude: [
        /\\node_modules\\flag-icon-css\\.*\.svg([\?\#].*)?$/,
    ]
  }, 
  {
    test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/flags/[name].[ext]')
    },
    include: [
        /\\node_modules\\flag-icon-css\\.*\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    ]
  },
```

Now all SVG files are handled as before - except for the flags. They are loaded from `img/flags/`. The files will be automatically copied into this folder on build and served from there.

One interesting thing to note: As I am working on Windows my include/exclude paths contain back-slashes - it does not work with forward slashes as the regex is compared with the path on the disc.

Answer (score 1):

You should move those SVG files into the `./static` folder - thus they won't be included in the bundle but will be directly copied to `./dist` folder and you will have to reference them using absolute URLs.

Comment: This does not answer my question unfortunately. Of course in the end I will load the svg files from ./static - but how do I instruct webpack to load it from there - and not to include it in the loader.

Comment: Exactly like I said - put the files in the static folder and then access them using absolute URL instead of relative one - e.g. `url("/flag_usa.svg")`